# Confusion Matrix with seaborn with different color scales per cell

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I want to create a plot of a confusion matrix with `True/False Positive/Negative`.

The goal is to have the numbers in the range `[0.0, 1.0]`, and for `True Negative/Positive`, the color scale be `red->green`, and for the `False Negative/Positive` for it to be `green->red`. I have not found anything in the seaborn documentation to do so, is it even possible? It would allow a quick glance over the data, and anything red would be a problem.

The goal would be left top and bottom right cells have a different color map than left bottom and right top. Is this possible?

Example code:

```
import numpy as np;
import seaborn as sns; 
sns.set_theme()
uniform_data = np.ndarray(shape=(2,2))
uniform_data[0][0] = 0.1
uniform_data[0][1] = 0.9
uniform_data[1][0] = 0.05
uniform_data[1][1] = 0.95
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, annot=True, cmap=sns.color_palette("vlag", as_cmap=True))
```

results in the image:

[image]

But what I would want is to be top left red (as 0.1 is a bad value here), and bottom right blue (as 0.95 is good here)

So something like this (done quickly with paint, so don't mind the errors, but the sentiment is there):
[image]

Comment: You should provide a minimal dataset and ideally a schematic of the expected graph

Comment: Added code to reproduce and images showcasing what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to invert the colors of the elements on the diagonal. The `data` argument of `sns.heatmap` decides on the colors, while the `annot=` argument can set something different for the annotation. Modifying the data and keeping the original for the annotation:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme()
uniform_data = np.ndarray(shape=(2, 2))
uniform_data[0][0] = 0.1
uniform_data[0][1] = 0.9
uniform_data[1][0] = 0.05
uniform_data[1][1] = 0.95
ax = sns.heatmap(np.abs(np.eye(2) - uniform_data), annot=uniform_data, cmap="vlag", vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

[image: sns.heatmap with some colors switched]